# Use shnsplit to split a FLAC file given a CUE file

Tags: command-line, audio, flac

## Table of Contents

- What I'm trying to do
- What I've tried

  - Attempt no. 1
  - Attempt no. 2
- The question

## What I'm trying to do

Let's suppose I have a FLAC file and a CUE file with the information to extract some parts from the FLAC file. Namely, the following parts

1. the track "My Foo 1 Foo" from 00:00 to 00:59
2. the track "My Foo 2 Foo" from 01:00 to 01:59
3. the track "My Foo 3 Foo" from 02:00 to 02:59
4. the track "My Foo 4 Foo" from 03:00 to 03:59

I know `shnsplit` can split a FLAC file given a CUE file. In fact, I tried to use `shnsplit`, but I haven't been able to get the result that I mentioned.

## What I've tried

By using the following command, I created a FLAC file. You could also use it to create one if you are looking for a sample FLAC file. The audio contains the count from the number 1 to the number 1000 which lasts 6 minutes and 52 seconds.

```sh
$ espeak --stdout "$(seq 1 1000 | tr '\n' ' ')" > main.wav
$ ffmpeg -y -i main.wav main.flac
```

You can use the following command to show the duration of the FLAC file.

```sh
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -print_format default=nk=1:nw=1 main.flac
```

```
412.812517
```

### Attempt no. 1

The code block below contains the file content of the file `main.cue` which I manually created.

```
FILE "foo.flac" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 1 Foo"
    INDEX 00 00:00
    INDEX 01 00:59

  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 2 Foo"
    INDEX 00 01:00
    INDEX 01 01:59

  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 3 Foo"
    INDEX 00 02:00
    INDEX 01 02:59

  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 4 Foo"
    INDEX 00 03:00
    INDEX 01 03:59
```

The code block below shows the `shnsplit` command which I used to split the file.

```sh
shnsplit -O always -f main.cue -t '%n - %t' -o flac main.flac
```

The code block below shows the command I used to show all FLAC files in the current directory along with their durations.

```sh
find -name '*.flac' ! -name 'main.flac' | sort | while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -print_format default=nk=1:nw=1 "$line"
done
```

```
./00 - pregap.flac
59.000000
./01 - My Foo 1 Foo.flac
60.000000
./02 - My Foo 2 Foo.flac
60.000000
./03 - My Foo 3 Foo.flac
60.000000
./04 - My Foo 4 Foo.flac
173.812517
```

This is not the result that I'm looking for because of two reasons. First, there's a file called `00 - pregap.flac` whose duration is 59 seconds. This file shoiuldn't exist because the first track (i.e. `My Foo 1 Foo`) starts at 00:00, so there isn't a pregap. Second, the file is expected to durate 60 seconds, however, it seems to span until the end of the FLAC file.

### Attempt no. 2

In contrast to attempt no. 1, in this attempt I didn't specify `INDEX 00`.

The code block below contains the file content of the file `main.cue` which I manually created.

```
FILE "foo.flac" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 1 Foo"
    INDEX 01 00:00

  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 2 Foo"
    INDEX 01 01:00

  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 3 Foo"
    INDEX 01 02:00

  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "My Foo 4 Foo"
    INDEX 01 03:00
```

The code block below shows the `shnsplit` command which I used to split the file.

```sh
shnsplit -O always -f main.cue -t '%n - %t' -o flac main.flac
```

The code block below shows the command I used to show all FLAC files in the current directory along with their durations.

```sh
find -name '*.flac' ! -name 'main.flac' | sort | while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=duration -print_format default=nk=1:nw=1 "$line"
done
```

```
./01 - My Foo 1 Foo.flac
60.000000
./02 - My Foo 2 Foo.flac
60.000000
./03 - My Foo 3 Foo.flac
60.000000
./04 - My Foo 4 Foo.flac
232.812517
```

Although, this attempt didn't create the file `pregap.flac`, this is not the result that I'm looking for because of one reason: the track `My Foo 4 Foo` lasts more than 3 minutes, the expected result is its duration to be 60 seconds as all the other tracks.

## The question

Could you provide a minimal working example on how to use `shnsplit` to get the result that I mentioned in the first section?